# use spark to sync cosmos data to snowflake and get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Null value appeared in non-nullable field` error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I use spark to sync cosmos data to snowflake,the code is like below:

```scala
var cosmosQuery = "SELECT * FROM c";
val readConfig = Config(Map(
      "Endpoint" -> endpoint,
      "Masterkey" -> cosmosKey,
      "Database" -> cosmosSourceDB,
      "Collection" -> cosmosSourceCollection,
      "ReadChangeFeed" -> "false",
      "query_custom" -> cosmosQuery // Optional
    ))

 // Connect via azure-cosmosdb-spark to create Spark DataFrame
 val df = ss.read.cosmosDB(readConfig)
 val sfOptions = Map(
    "sfURL" -> "***.snowflakecomputing.com",
    "sfUser" -> sfUser,
    "sfRole" -> sfRole,
    "pem_private_key" -> pem_private_key,
    "sfDatabase" -> sfDatabase,
    "sfSchema" -> sfSchema,
    "sfWarehouse" -> sfWarehouse
 )
df.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
        .options(sfOptions)
        .option("dbtable", "cosmosSourceCollection")
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .save()
```

but when I run it, there is an error in the df.write.format, the error is:

```
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.CloudStorage$class.uploadRDD(CloudStorageOperations.scala:771)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.InternalAzureStorage.uploadRDD(CloudStorageOperations.scala:901)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.CloudStorage$class.upload(CloudStorageOperations.scala:528)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.InternalAzureStorage.upload(CloudStorageOperations.scala:901)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.StageWriter$.writeToStage(StageWriter.scala:209)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.package$.writeRDD(package.scala:50)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeWriter.save(SnowflakeWriter.scala:74)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at com.fti.cosmos.AppendToSnowflake$.main(AppendToSnowflake.scala:140)
    at com.fti.cosmos.AppendToSnowflake.main(AppendToSnowflake.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null value appeared in non-nullable field:
If the schema is inferred from a Scala tuple/case class, or a Java bean, please try to use scala.Option[_] or other nullable types (e.g. java.lang.Integer instead of int/scala.Int).
```

and I add read option like:

```scala
val df = ss.read
      .option("spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled", true)
      .option("spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.samplingSize", 10000)
      .option("spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.forceNullableProperties", false).cosmosDB(readConfig)
```

it still get same error, so how can I fix this error? is there any option can add to avoid this error? I refer to the official document [cosmos-spark-guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/create-sql-api-spark) and could not find a suitable option in it.

Comment: Are any of the columns on the table defined with NOT NULL?

Comment: Which Cosmos DB Spark Connector version are you using? The null seems to be coming from the snowflake write flow based on the stack trace, maybe the schema you are passing to the writer does not match the inferred schema? Why not use the same schema on both reader and writer?

Comment: I did not make any changes to the inferred schema, just spark.read and spark.write. So it 
 is a very strange question